# Conditional FluentValidation in mvc 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0

**My Model is as below**

```
[Validator(typeof(PersonValidator))]
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {

      RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(4, 10)
        .When(per => per.Id.ToUpper() == "FOO");
    }
}
```

**My controller is as below**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersonAction(Person p)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

i want the following validation been set using Fluent Validation

1. If **Id** == 'foo',then **Name** should have its **Length** validation
2. If **Id** !== 'foo',then **Name** should **NOT** have **Length** validation

But Lenght validation seems to be always getting applied. i.e. irrespective of what is the value of Id, What am i missing ?

Comment: what you have done so far? any error?

Comment: i tried but am not able to basically get any correct approch as am very new to Fluent validation. Infact today is the first time i have heard of it and am implementing it in my application

Comment: the same thing is done [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8086267/4154016) .go through this link

Comment: i did check this before writing a question as i could not make out how to implement. It would be great if you could post a sample code.

Comment: You can use When() method in your validator

Comment: @EvgenyLevin: I tried with "When" ( and have edited the question with what is tried), but still it seems to be not working. Could you please take a look at the approach i did (it's in the question itself now).

Comment: @ismailbaig your example is exact as answer I planned to post. I have no concrete answer, but try to replace length validation with custom validation using Must() method and try to watch at your model in Debug mode. It can help to figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
When(x => string.Equals(x.Id, "foo", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase), () => 
{
   RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(4, 10).WithMessage([YOUR MESSAGE]);
});
```